# CSS Sprite Display Inline-Block Displays Incorrectly with IE Browser

Tags: asp.net, css, visual-studio-2010, internet-explorer

I have a website I created using Sprite controls and AJAX controls.

I can run the website in Chrome, and it looks just like the JSFIDDLE version.

However, when I turn to IE10 and try displaying the full website, my menu links go UP and DOWN instead of LEFT to RIGHT.

In the JSFIDDLE version (http://jsfiddle.net/JjNrb/), I have to remove the AJAX stuff and replace the `<asp:LinkButton>` controls with `<a href="#">` tags, but this appears to be what ASP.NET does when it renders the webpage.

The CSS is fairly short, there is no Javascript (yet) and no other CSS.

### What could be making my page show up like this?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: What mode is the browser in? Press F12 to bring up the dev tools window. If it says "Quirks mode" or "Compatibility mode", then you've found your problem (or at least, you've found *a* problem!).

Comment: *Browser Mode: **IE10 Compat View*** and *Document Mode: **IE7 standards***

Comment: Damn. Switching to Browser Mode IE9 made the problems go away, though.

Comment: If this was happening on your local dev system (as it appears to be in the address bar in the screenshot) then it's likely caused by a setting in IE that turns compatibility mode on for local intranet sites. You should probably turn that off. See the Tools menu for the Compatibility View Settings window.

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much all I had to do, @Spudley.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you are in standards mode - does your page start with ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Comment: It does, Woody. Does **strict** hurt anything? `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">`

Comment: If you fire up the IE10 developer tools (F12) you should see browser mode and document mode menus - you're looking for "standards" mode. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode.  Also you can try flipping the rendering mode into standards mode using those menus and see if the layout problem goes away - if it does, that'll be your problem.

Comment: That's my problem! I can't force the whole world to hit F12 and go to IE9 mode, though. Is there a way to have my CSS run as CSS 1?

Comment: Change the doctype to just be "<!DOCTYPE html>" in your HTML !